# Insert an Unordered Map Into an Unordered Set in C++

Tags: c++, stl, insert, unordered-map, unordered-set

Idea: I want a data structure to hold multiple key/pair values of character and character counts in a word. This way, with 5 character counts in a "character counts set" and given any word, I can quickly tell whether an anagram exists in the set by calculating the character count of the given word.

Problem: I am getting an error while trying to insert an `unordered_map<char, int>` into a `unordered_set<unordered_map<char, int>>`.

Code:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>

int main()
{
  std::unordered_set<std::unordered_map<char, int>> used_char_counts;
  std::unordered_map<char, int> char_counts;
  used_char_counts.insert(char_counts);
}
```

Error:
`error: no matching function for call to 'std::unordered_set<std::unordered_map<char, int> >::insert(std::unordered_map<char, int>*)'`

Compiler Version:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)
```

Comment: Do we need all of this code to [duplicate the issue](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/060011ef7027452b)?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'll update the question, but that is essentially the problem.

Comment: `std::unordered_set::insert()` is a C++17 feature. For earlier versions, I think `std::unordered_set::emplace()` is the right function. Although my version of g++, g++ 5.4.0, still does not seem to support it.

Comment: @RSahu from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert) it looks like only inserting nodes is from C++17. The `insert` he's trying to call should be there since C++11

Comment: @scohe001, makes sense now. Sounds like the OP's problem is lack of support from the compiler.

Comment: @RSahu I'm not sure...when I try on [ideone](https://ideone.com/962vql) it looks like it's choosing the wrong candidate...

Comment: @scohe001, Your link to ideone points to use of g++ 6.3. That version supports more of the C++11 features than g++ 5.4. Note to OP: Please post your compiler version info.

Comment: @RSahu Updated the post

Comment: `std::unordered_set` requires a hash on the key item.  [The default set of hash functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) probably will not fit for `unordered_map`.  So @AkshayKalose, you may have to provide a hash function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks! To avoid this problem, I changed my implementation to use `set<vector<int>>` with each vector being initialized with 256 values. This avoids hashing and also having to implement a < function for the inside type.